# How to manage mysql offset and limit in pagination

Tags: mysql, pagination, limit, offset

A table containing huge amount of data where data insertion rate is almost 5 rows per second.
I am fetching data from this table with infinite pagination using limit and offset along with left joins in descending order of created_date(it stores the insertion timstamp).

So , by taking the time into consideration it happens to fetch duplicate data from the table.

Suppose , currently I have 1000 data , for :

**Expected Output:**

total records: 1000

1. 1st fetch:   limit: 10, offset: 0 (Expected:  1000, 999, 998, ....
   991)
2. 2nd fetch: limit : 10, offset: 10 (Expected:  990,...,981)
3. 3rd
   fetch: limit : 10, offset: 20 (Expected:  980,..., 971)

**Actual data :**

1. total records: 1000

   1st fetch:   limit: 10, offset: 0 (Actual:  1000, 999, 998, .... 991)
2. total records: 1005

   2nd fetch: limit : 10, offset: 10 (Actual:  995,...,986)

   Repeated record: 995,994,993,992,991
3. total records: 1012

   3rd fetch: limit : 10, offset: 20 (Actual:  992,..., 983)

   Repeated record: 992,991,990,989,988,987,986

Is there any locking for the current requests or procedure in mysql to fetch the data properly without adding another where clause like record id greater than the first fetched like that ?

If any further info is required for the solution/queries, please comment.

My query is:

```
SELECT `tab_a`.*, `tab_b`.`likes`, `tab_b`.`comment`, `tab_b`.`share` 
FROM `tab_a` 
LEFT JOIN `tab_b` ON `tab_a`.`id` = `tab_b`.`post_id` 
WHERE post_position IN (?) AND (post_date BETWEEN ? AND ?) 
GROUP BY `tab_a`.`id` ORDER BY `tab_a`.`id` DESC, `tab_b`.`created_date` DESC 
LIMIT 9 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Your query is nonsensical, which leaves me at a bit of a loss to help further. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

Try to add column `tab_a`.`id` into where clause. Everytime you request the query, try to add value of last `tab_a`.`id` (let say default is max `tab_a`.`id`=1000).

First time query:

```
select `tab_a`.*, `tab_b`.`likes`, `tab_b`.`comment`, `tab_b`.`share` from `tab_a` 
left join `tab_b` on `tab_a`.`id` = `tab_b`.`post_id` 
where `tab_a`.`id` <= 1000 and post_position in (?) and (post_date between ? and ?) 
group by `tab_a`.`id` order by `tab_a`.`id` desc, `tab_b`.`created_date` desc 
limit 9 offset 0
```

Second time query, the last `tab_a`.`id` from first query result is 990, then query should be

```
select `tab_a`.*, `tab_b`.`likes`, `tab_b`.`comment`, `tab_b`.`share` from `tab_a` 
left join `tab_b` on `tab_a`.`id` = `tab_b`.`post_id` 
where `tab_a`.`id` <= 990 and post_position in (?) and (post_date between ? and ?) 
group by `tab_a`.`id` order by `tab_a`.`id` desc, `tab_b`.`created_date` desc 
limit 9 offset 0
```

Comment: I think you only understood the question. Thanks for your reply. But I was searching for some other solution other than adding another where clause.